# Need only 00:00:00 time format in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing webpage in which i have used text field and set it's type as time. But it is giving me 00:00 AM/PM format.
I want 00:00:00 as time format.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery timepicker

`$(function(){
   $('#example').timepicker(); 
});`

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sgbangale/h61rtas0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `step` attribute to the element. **Note:** You might want to implement your own `time` type if you need cross-browser support. `input<type=time>` does not work in Safari.

```html
<input type="time" step="1">
```

In case you need own implementation, here it is. Requires no third part library. To access the value just get the value of the `timepicker` div
using `document.getElementById("timepicker").getAttribute("data-value");`

```js
function updateTime()
{
    function getFormattedValue(value)
    {
        return value>9?value:"0"+value;
    }
    
    var hour = document.getElementById("hour").value,
        minute = document.getElementById("minute").value || 0,
        second = document.getElementById("second").value || 0;
    var time = getFormattedValue(hour)+":"+getFormattedValue(minute)+":"+getFormattedValue(second);
    var timeelem = document.getElementById("timepicker");
    timeelem.setAttribute("data-value", time);
    console.log(time);
    console.log(timeelem.getAttribute("data-value"));
}
```

```html
<div id="timepicker" data-value="">
<input id="hour" type="number" max="23" min="0" onchange="updateTime()">
<input id="minute" type="number" max="59" min="0" onchange="updateTime()">
<input id="second" type="number" max="59" min="0" onchange="updateTime()">
</div>
```